# Unicorn & Pry in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, pry

I'm unable to use pry with Unicorn as I get booted out of my prompt after sometime.  Here is a quick overview:

In a custom action in a controller I have this:

```
  def assign
    binding.pry
  end
```

Getting to this route is no problem and I even get the familar `pry` prompt like so:

```
     8: def assign
     9:
 => 10:   binding.pry
    11: end

[1] pry(#<RolesController>)>
```

After a period of about a minute I get this which kicks me out of the pry prompt:

```
[3] pry(#<RolesController>)> E, [2014-08-21T16:29:01.698472 #4780] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:4852 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2014-08-21T16:29:01.721420 #4780] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4852 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
I, [2014-08-21T16:29:01.745491 #5109]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Is there a way to not kill a process while in pry?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing my `timeout` configuration in my `config/unicorn.rb` file like so:

```
if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development"
  worker_processes 1
  timeout 10000
else
  worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
  timeout 15
  preload_app true
end
```

Comment: @Ich — Did you `export RAILS_ENV='development'` in your `.profile`/`.bash_profile` or whatever else you (barbarians :D) use? Then don't forget to "source" it; `. ~/.profile`

Comment: Thank you. `if Rails.env.development?` can be used as well

Answer (score 3):

I think for proper debugging in development you have to configure unicorn not to timeout in dev mode. The unicorn worker is waiting for the response of your controller action you pry'd into and hence it does not get an response within the set timeout window the process is killed.